# jQuery .toggle not completing

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a function that is using the jQuery `.toggle()` to hide a div.  The function get's called during 2 different scenarios.  When the page loads the function get's called repeatedly to set up the page and then it gets called on a one off basis after user action.  After the user action I can see that the div is getting updated correctly to include `style="display:none;`" but when the function get's called repeatedly during page load I can see the div only get's updated with the word style and the `="display:none;"` is left out.

Here is the jquery I am trying to use.
`$("#divAnswerUpdate" + qc_ID).toggle();`

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: without seeing anything else, its hard to say. My first guess is you are adding same ID's to the page, and that causes a conflict for `toggle()`

Comment: You need to tell us what you're not telling us and we can help. It seems like you're not calling it twice because it would leave a style="display:block" around instead of an empty style tag.

Comment: You should post your actual javascript-code. Just one curious thing; you say the function get's called repeatedly on page load. The actual code is executed in a millisecond. Unless you use setTimeout or delay on your toggle, the animations would happen so quickly you would not see it.

Comment: Why are you calling the function repeatedly? Please show your whole function and the way you call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what my issue was.  I was not explicitly setting style before calling toggle.  I changed the call from toggle to hide and am now getting the behavior I expected.